# rails group by utc date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, utc

I have a time field in table "timestamp without time zone". When record is saved to database, the utc time might be a different day compared to the local time. However, I need to group the records by date. Hence, I am doing something like this:

```
result = transmissions.joins(:report).where('reports.time::timestamp::date = ?', record.time.to_date)
```

The problem is if the utc date is on a different date than local time, then that record is not included in result. Any ideas how to get the right result?

And apparently I cannot change the "without time zone" either:

[Rails database-specific data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713791/rails-database-specific-data-type)

It says:
"concluded that the default ActiveRecord datetime and timestamp column types in schema migrations cannot be modified to force PostgreSQL to use timestamp with time zone."

So I have no idea how to group by date, as obviously something like this is wrong:

```
Unit.where(id: 1100).first.reports.order("DATE(time)").group("DATE(time)").count
 => {"2013-12-14"=>19, "2013-12-15"=>5}
```

That return value is completely wrong. All 25 records should be on 2013-12-14 and 0 records on 2013-12-15.

Comment: Here is a blog post i wrote on rails and timezones http://jessehouse.com/blog/2013/11/15/working-with-timezones-and-ruby-on-rails/ - it does not cover your situation, but i am thinking you might need to use postgres 'at time zone' or do the grouping in ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your records are timestamped with a particular UTC offset, you can try passing in the start and end times of the date in question in UTC format to your query:

```
result = transmissions.joins(:report).where('reports.time >= ? AND reports.time < ?', record.time.midnight.utc, (record.time.midnight + 1.day).utc)
```

**Explanation**:

[`midnight`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-midnight) is a Rails method on an instance of `Time` that returns the `Time` object that represents midnight on the date of the original `Time` object. Similarly, `record.time.midnight + 1.day` returns the `Time` object representing midnight of the following day. *Then*, converting both `Time` objects – which are presumably timestamped in a standard UTC offset – to UTC creates a time period representing midnight-to-midnight for the system timezone *in UTC format* (**not** midnight *in UTC time*), which is precisely what you're seeking to query.

Comment: This seemed to have worked. Can you explain a little more what's going on with "midnight.utc"?

Comment: Sure – explanation attached. Since this worked, would you kindly consider upvoting/accepting this question as correct?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like `result = transmissions.joins(:report).where('reports.time >= ? AND reports.time <= ?', record.time.beginning_of_day.utc, record.time.end_of_day.utc)`

The `.utc` part may not be necessary.